# My solution for Euler Project #3 is too slow

Tags: haskell, primes, prime-factoring

I'm new to Haskell and tinkering around with the Euler Project problems. My solution for problem #3 is far too slow. At first I tried this:

```
-- Problem 3
-- The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
-- What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

problem3 = max [ x | x <- [1..n], (mod n x) == 0, n /= x]
    where n = 600851475143
```

Then I changed it to return all `x` and not just the largest one.

```
problem3 = [ x | x <- [1..n], (mod n x) == 0, n /= x]
        where n = 600851475143
```

After 30 minutes, the list is still being processed and the output looks like this

`[1,71,839,1471,6857,59569,104441,486847,1234169,5753023,10086647,87625999,408464633,716151937`

Why is it so slow? Am I doing something terribly wrong or is it normal for this sort of task?

Comment: Fun fact: You're touching about 600 billion numbers. Even if each number took a single CPU clock cycle (which is completely unrealistic) that would still take dozens of seconds on the most highly clocked CPUs widely available. So yeah, this approach is infeasible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your solution, there are about 600 billion possible numbers. As noted by delnan, making every check of the number quicker is not going to make much difference, we must limit the number of candidates.

Your solution does not seem to be correct either. `59569 = 71 * 839` isn't it? The question
only asks for prime factors. Notice that `71` and `839` is in your list so you are
doing something right. In fact, you are trying to find all factors.

I think the most dramatic effect you get simply by dividing away the factor before continuing.

```
euler3 = go 2 600851475143
  where
    go cand num
      | cand == num           = [num]
      | cand `isFactorOf` num = cand : go cand       (num `div` cand)
      | otherwise             =        go (cand + 1) num

isFactorOf a b = b `mod` a == 0
```

This may seem like an obvious optimization but it relies on the fact that if both `a` and `b` divides `c` and `a` is coprime to `b` then `a` divides `c/b`.

If you want to do more, the common "Only check until the square root" trick has been
mentioned here. The same trick can be applied to this problem, but the performance gain does not show, unfortunately, on this instance:

```
euler3 = go 2 600851475143
  where
    go cand num
      | cand*cand > num       = [num]
      | cand `isFactorOf` num = cand : go cand       (num `div` cand)
      | otherwise             =        go (cand + 1) num

isFactorOf a b = b `mod` a == 0
```

Here, when a candidate is larger than the square root of the remaining number (`num`), we know that `num` must be a prime and therefore a prime factor of the original
number (`600851475143`).

It is possible to remove even more candidates by only considering prime numbers,
but this is slightly more advanced because you need to make a reasonably performant
way of generating primes. See [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers) for ways of doing that.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, since it reduces the running time so significantly. I'd recommend checking `cand*cand > num` instead in the first guard condition. That will implement the common "only check up to the square root" trick (without actually taking a square root). You can also keep track of the odd number to add (1 + 3 = 2^2, 1 + 3 + 5 = 3^2, 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 4^2) to reduce that squaring from a multiplication to a couple additions.

Comment: @Olathe, thanks for the suggestion. I added a paragraph about it. The difference in performance on this one instance is unfortunately not noticeable.

Comment: let's refactor, `euler3 n = go 2 n where ...`. Now, trying `[ euler3 x | x<-[600851475143..]]`, what about the performance gain there (of testing only up to the sqrt)?

Comment: @WillNess , On that benchmark the "Only check up to sqrt" trick is crucial. The difference is less than a second versus minutes.

Comment: sorry, changed the test on you; it should be `take 7 [ euler3 x | x<-[600851475143..]]`. I think the importance of this technique should be stressed. --- btw if we only want the factorization of *one* number, finding primes to test on is not advantageous.

Comment: @WillNess , well the result is more or less the same, the square root check is important there too because `600851475149` is a prime.

Comment: exactly. so it is very much *not* insignificant, in general. :)

Comment: "This may seem like an obvious optimization but it relies on the fact that if both a and b divides c and a is not equal to b then a divides c/b." I stared at this for a while trying to find the obvious proof before realising that it's just not true. For example, take a=3,b=9 and c=18. Then a|c, b|c and a!=b but neither 3|2 nor 9|6. This is true iff a and b are coprime. In this case, we're looking for prime factors, so that's okay, but this code isn't equivalent to the code above.

Comment: did you know that if 10 edits or more are made to a post, it turns community wiki, and you don't get rep points for it anymore? :)

Answer (score 3):

It's doing a lot of work! (It's also going to give you the wrong answer, but that's a separate issue!)

There are a few very quick ways you could speed it up by thinking about the problem a little first:

- You are applying your function over all numbers `1..n`, and checking each one of them to ensure it isn't `n`. Instead, you could just go over all numbers `1..n-1` and skip out `n` different checks (small though they are).
- The answer is odd, so you can very quickly filter out any even numbers by going from `1..(n-1)/2` and checking for `2x` instead of `x`.
- If you think about it, all factors occur in pairs, so you can in fact just search from `1..sqrt(n)` (or `1..sqrt(n)/2` if you ignore even numbers) and output pairs of numbers in each step.

Not related to the performance of this function, but it's worth noting that what you've implemented here will find all of the factors of a number, whereas what you want is only the largest prime factor.  So either you have to test each of your divisors for primality (which is going to be slow, again) or you can implement the two in one step. You probably want to look at 'sieves', the most simple being the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and how you can implement them.

Answer (score 1):

A complete factorization of a number can take a long time for big numbers.  For Project Euler problems, a brute force solution (which this is) is usually not enough to find the answer in your lifetime.

Hint: you do not need to find *all* prime factors, just the biggest one.

Comment: I see. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***: The two things you were doing non-optimally, are: not stopping at the square root, and not dividing out each smallest factor, as they are found.

---

Here's a little derivation of the (2nd) factorization code shown in [the answer by HaskellElephant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946730/849891). We start with your code:

```
f1 n = [ x | x <- [2..n], rem n x == 0]
n3 = 600851475143

Prelude> f1 n3
[71,839,1471,6857,59569,104441,486847Interrupted.
```

So it doesn't finish in any reasonable amount of time, and some of the numbers it produces are not *prime*... But instead of adding primality check to the list comprehension, let's notice that 71 *is* prime. The first number produced by `f1 n` is ***the smallest divisor*** of `n`, and thus it ***is prime***. If it weren't, we'd find *its* smallest divisor first - a contradiction.

So, we can **divide it out**, and [continue searching](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:iterate) for the prime factors of newly reduced number:

```
f2 n = tail $ iterate (\(_,m)-> (\f->(f, quot m f)) . head $ f1 m) (1,n) 

Prelude> f2 n3
[(71,8462696833),(839,10086647),(1471,6857),(6857,1),(*** Exception: Prelude.hea
d: empty list
```

(the error, because `f1 1 == []`). We're done! (*6857* is the answer, here...). Let's wrap it up:

```
takeUntil p xs = foldr (\x r -> if p x then [x] else x:r) [] xs
pfactors1 n = map fst . takeUntil ((==1).snd) . f2 $ n   -- prime factors of n
```

---

Trying out our newly minted solution,

```
Prelude> map pfactors1 [n3..]
[[71,839,1471,6857],[2,2,2,3,3,1259Interrupted.
```

suddenly we hit a new inefficiency wall, on numbers without small divisors. But if `n = a*b` and `1 < a <= b`, then `a*a <= a*b == n` and so it is enough to test only until the ***square root*** of a number, to find its smallest divisor.

```
f12 n = [ x | x <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) [2..n], rem n x == 0] ++ [n]
f22 n = tail $ iterate (\(_,m)-> (\f->(f, quot m f)) . head $ f12 m) (1,n) 
pfactors2 n = map fst . takeUntil ((==1).snd) . f22 $ n
```

What couldn't finish in half an hour now finishes in under one second (on a typical performant box):

```
Prelude> f12 n3
[71,839,1471,6857,59569,104441,486847,600851475143]
```

All the divisors above `sqrt n3` were not needed at all. We unconditionally add `n` itself as the last divisor in `f12` so it is able to handle prime numbers:

```
Prelude> f12 (n3+6)
[600851475149]
```

Since `n3 / sqrt n3 = sqrt n3 ~= 775146`, your original attempt at `f1 n3` should have taken ***about a week*** to finish. That's how important this optimization is, of stopping at the square root.

```
Prelude> f22 n3
[(71,8462696833),(839,10086647),(1471,6857),(6857,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,
1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)Interrupted
```

We've apparently traded the *"Prelude.head: empty list"* error for a non-terminating - but *productive* - behavior.

---

Lastly, we break `f22` up in two parts and fuse them each into the other functions, for a somewhat simplified code. Also, we **won't start over anew**, as `f12` does, searching for the smallest divisor from *2* all the time, anymore:

```
-- smallest factor of n, starting from d. directly jump from sqrt n to n.
smf (d,n) = head $ [ (x, quot n x) | x <- takeWhile ((<=n).(^2)) [d..]
                                   , rem n x == 0] ++ [(n,1)]

pfactors n = map fst . takeUntil ((==1).snd) . tail . iterate smf $ (2,n)
```

This expresses *guarded (co)recursion* through a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) [`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:iterate), and is functionally equivalent to that code mentioned above. The following now runs smoothly, and we're even able to find a pair of [twin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) as a bonus there:

```
Prelude Saga> map pfactors [n3..]
[[71,839,1471,6857],[2,2,2,3,3,1259,6628403],[5,120170295029],[2,13,37,227,27514
79],[3,7,7,11,163,2279657],[2,2,41,3663728507],[600851475149],[2,3,5,5,19,31,680
0809],[600851475151],[2,2,2,2,37553217197],[3,3,3,211,105468049],[2,7,11161,3845
351],[5,67,881,2035853],[2,2,3Interrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Euler Project #3. It takes only 1.22 sec on my Macbook Air.

First we should find all factors of the given number. But we know, that even numbers can't be prime numbers (except number 2). So, to solve Euler Project #3 we need not all, but only odd factors:

```
    getOddFactors num = [ x | x <- [3,5..num], num `rem` x == 0 ]
```

But we can optimize this function. If we plan to find a factor of *num* greater than *sqrt num*, we should have another factor which is less than *sqrt num* - and these possible factors we have found already. Hence, we can limit our list of possible factors by *sqrt num*:

```
    getOddFactors num = [ x | x <- [3, 5..(floor.sqrt.fromIntegral) num], 
                          num `rem` x == 0 ]
```

Next we want to know which of our odd factors of *num* are prime numbers:

```
    isPrime number = [ x | x <- [3..(floor.sqrt.fromIntegral) number], 
                       number `rem` x == 0] == []
```

Next we can filter odd factors of *num* with the function *isPrime* to find all prime factors of *num*. But to use laziness of Haskell to optimize our solution, we apply function *filter isPrime* to the **reversed** list of odd factors of the num. As soon as our function finds the first value which is prime number, Haskell stops computations and returns solution:

```
    largestPrimeFactor = head . filter isPrime . reverse . getOddDivisors
```

Hence, the solution is:

```
    ghci> largestPrimeFactor 600851475143
    6857
    (1.22 secs, 110646064 bytes)
```